# Bug in android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi fellow android developers,

I'm trying to implement a multi-pane layout as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html) and an example implementation can be found in the codesample ["HoneycombGallery"](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html).

The only thing I changed is, that instead of using the normal getFragmentManager() I use the support-libraries and therefore the "getSupportFragmentManager()". But now I have the following problem:

The getSupportFragmentManager().findViewById() returns a reference to a fragment even when the fragment is not on the screen :/

As you cann easily see, the example implementation uses this technique to differ between the to possibilyties, but the getSupportFragmentManager() returns a reference to a fragment in situations (for example after a orientation change and the second fragment disappeared as it is no longer in the layout) where it shouldn't.

Has anyone also tried to get Multi-Pane-Layout working with the support-Fragments and FragmentManager?

Any hint is highly appreciated :)

Cheers
Ali3n

PS.: I could post some code if requested, but it actually is nearly the same code as in the example ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem, by not asking the FragmentManager for the fragment, instead I ask my layout for the view.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and registered an issue on Android issue tracker.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40796

Please star if anyone having this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Voted on it and eager waiting for an answer :)